# TSQL Distinct within subquery using xml

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have the following table structure:

Table1 - List of Possible Region/Market Options

```
Region  |  Market
--------+----------------
EMEA    |  London
NA      |  Omaha
EMEA    |  Another City
```

Table2 - Holds the Markets that were selected as impacts

```
RequestID   |  Market
------------+----------------
123         | London
123         | Omaha
456         | Another City
```

Within my stored procedure, I am trying to create a distinct list of Region/Markets that are impacted based on `Table2`. The end result will be a distinct list of regions with all of the markets within them that are impacted.

In this case, there are two impacts from the `EMEA` region but I wouldn't want `EMEA` to show up twice.

When I was doing this on a single request, I was able to create a temp table and insert the data into it and then accomplish what I needed to do. However, this is pulling all of the results and I need to do this within the query and I am not sure how..

This code works fine if I wasn't getting the distinct data from it. Otherwise, it throws the error:

> The xml data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

Is there another way I can accomplish this within a sub-query/sub-select?

```
 ...
 (SELECT DISTINCT 
      region,
      (SELECT m.market
       FROM dbo.bs_ToolRequests_MarketOptions AS m
       INNER JOIN dbo.BS_ToolRequests_ImpactedMarkets AS ma ON ma.market = m.market
       WHERE m.region = mo.region
         AND ma.requestID = t.requestID
       FOR XML PATH ('options'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('markets'))
  FROM   
      dbo.BS_ToolRequests_MarketOptions AS mo
  FOR XML PATH ('regions'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('impactedMarkets')),
```

Expected result:

```
<impactedMarkets>
  <regions>
    <region>EMEA</region>
    <markets>
       <options>
         <market>London</market>
       </options>
       <options>
         <market>Another City</market>
       </options>
     </markets>
  </regions>
</impactedMarkets>
```

Comment: Should table2 be "Region" since you listed the cities instead of markets from table1?

Comment: Can you show the intended output sample you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use DISTINCT keyword in the SELECT statement of derived table

```
 ...
 (SELECT region,
          (SELECT m.market
           FROM dbo.bs_ToolRequests_MarketOptions AS m
           INNER JOIN dbo.BS_ToolRequests_ImpactedMarkets AS ma ON ma.market = m.market
           WHERE m.region = mo.region
             AND ma.requestID = t.requestID
           FOR XML PATH ('options'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('markets'))
      FROM   
          (SELECT DISTINCT region FROM dbo.BS_ToolRequests_MarketOptions) AS mo
FOR XML PATH ('regions'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('impactedMarkets')),
```